# Docker connection refused on all ports except 5000

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have just started with Docker. I have installed Docker Toolbox for Windows. I was trying out a sample Flask app to understand how things work. But I am stuck!. I am trying to access my app like this `http://docker-machine-ip : port number` but every time I do, I get '{docker-machine ip} refused to connect.'

I get no exceptions during the building and deploying stages. I also did `docker ps` to see that container is running. I even tried to access it via Kitematic but still no luck. Below are details related to the app

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Flask inside Docker shakel!!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:2.7
MAINTAINER Shekhar Gulati "shekhargulati84@gmail.com"
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

The docker commands I used for building and running are:

```
docker-machine ip default //To get docker machine ip
docker build -t flask-app .
docker run -d -p 6000:6000 flask-app
```

I have Windows 7 64 bit. Please let me know if any more info is required.

P.S. **However I noticed that if I map my container to 5000 port it will run fine but on any other port I get connection refused**

I don't know what am I missing here. This is my first attempt at Docker and I have googled for 4 hrs to find a solution but nothing is working. So it might be a very dumb mistake I am doing somewhere :).anyhow any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `docker run -d -p 6000:5000 flask-app` to bind your in-container flask application to your host machine's 6000 port.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you said but now I am getting  'The webpage at http://192.168.99.100:6000 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.'

Comment: Maybe you can try to relaunch your application. If you can run it well with `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-app`. It absolutely can run well with `docker run -d -p 6000:5000 flask-app` if your host machines's 6000 port is not used.

Comment: I restarted docker after stopping all containers. Rebuild my app again and then run it with the above mentioned command but still 'The webpage at 192.168.99.100:6000 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.'

Comment: Hey!!!..I used a different port other than 6000 like 4000, 7000 and it worked,..Thank you so much for all the help..Its 7 in the morning and I finally got it working :D. Now I can sleep in peace. Cheers. Please let me know how I can mark this ass accepted answer?

Comment: Um...So it seems chrome cached this web site address 192.168.99.100:6000 because you mapped your application to 6000 port before. After changing to another port, it works. Good ni.. morning, just mind it after waking up.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't set the port for your flask application, which is port `5000` by default.

From [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/):

> port – the port of the webserver. Defaults to 5000 or the port defined in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I didn't know that because I have never used Flask.I was just trying to get something up and running to understand Docker. Well can't I just map the port of the flask web server 5000 to a different host machine port let say 4500.